# EditPlus Regex - How to replace group 1 followed by 0

Tags: regex, replace, zero, editplus

I'm trying to replace with Regex's EditPlus, values that contain comma-separated numbers and two decimal points, so they have 3 decimal points, adding a zero to the end. But my attempts eventually delete the value of the group instead of adding the zero to the end. The text is from a csv file, tab separated, over 12000 lines.

The Text to replace (just example):

```
Car 48,589  27,56   NULL    NULL
Bike    NULL    12,258  NULL    45,896
Bus NULL    11,23   NULL    85,25
Truck   23,45   NULL    45,458  NULL
Boat    45,89   74,12   NULL    NULL
```

Find Regex String:

```
(\t[0-9]{2},[0-9]{2})([^0-9]|$)
```

Replace Regex String attempts:

```
1. $10$2   // delete String Group 1
2. $1\0$2  // make a copy of group 1 until the end
```

The Expected result is:

```
Car 48,589  27,560  NULL    NULL
Bike    NULL    12,258  NULL    45,896
Bus NULL    11,230  NULL    85,250
Truck   23,450  NULL    45,458  NULL
Boat    45,890  74,120  NULL    NULL
```

Comment: Your pattern contains 1 capturing group, why are you trying with `$2`? Try `(\t[0-9]{2},[0-9]{2})([^0-9]|$)` and replace with `${1}0$2`.

Comment: @Wiktor Sorry, there have been so many attempts I've copied the wrong Find Regex String. The correct one was this: `(\ t [0-9] {2}, [0-9] {2}) ([^ 0-9] | $)`. With this pattern can be match with values at the end of line. The 
Replace `${1}0$2` don't works in EditPlus Regex, i tried.

Comment: Then try `\10\2`. If EditPlus supports POSIX style backreferences like this, it should work.

Comment: The result is the same as `$10$2`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that expression \10 does not mean \1 (the first fount instance) and 0. It means found instance number ten.

You can do the replacement in two steps: add some placeholder symbols that are not in you file, e.x. @@@@@

[image]

And in the second step replace the placeholder with 0

[image]

And the result is:

[image]

The \2 is needed to correctly work with the numbers at the end of line, like in line number 3.

Comment: Sorry, there have been so many attempts I've copied the wrong Find Regex String. The correct one was this: `(\t[0-9]{2},[0-9]{2})([^0-9]|$)`. With this pattern can be match with values at the end of line. But anyway, thanks for your response, I was hoping I did not need 2 steps, but there's no other way. I'll use these two steps.